# ¿Cómo conseguir la ruta correcta?

Tags: javascript

Estoy tratando de hacer un `fetch` a archivos para poder visualizarlos en un textarea en texto plano (solo uno a la vez), pero no consigo lo que necesito gracias a que cuando selecciono el archivo mediante el `input type="file"`, el valor siempre me saldrá con `C://fakepath/`

```js
    document.body.innerHTML = `<input type="file" name="file">
<button type="button" class="intro">>></button>
<br>
<textarea></textarea>`;

    document.querySelector('.intro').addEventListener('click', ()=>{
        makeFetch();
    });

function makeFetch(){
    let tri = document.querySelector('input').value;
    console.log(tri);
    let url = tri.replace('C:\\fakepath\\', '');
    console.log(url);

    fetch(url)
    .then(response => response.text())
    .then(data => printJs(data));
}

function printJs(d){
    console.log(d);
    document.querySelector('textarea').value = d;
}
```

Lo que he intentado es quitarle el `C://fakepath/` con un `replace`, pero al final nunca me queda el resto de ruta relativa...

Comment: Leí la pregunta dos veces y no me queda claro cual es tu escenario. Creo que sería mejor si preparas un [mcve].

Comment: editado @jachguate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No puedes utilizar `fetch()` para obtener un recurso local, pues `fecth()`, por naturaleza, es para obtener recursos del servidor (de allí su nombre, que en español vendría a ser algo como *traer* o *recuperar*).

Si quieres obtener la ruta del archivo, me temo que la respuesta es:

**no se puede obtener la ruta del archivo seleccionado**.

Por razones de seguridad, el navegador no entrega esa información.

En cambio, si quieres obtener el contenido del fichero (local) que ha seleccionado el usuario, puedes valerte del [objeto `FileReader()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader), al que le pasas el archivo mismo.

Un poco de código vale más que 1000 palabras:

```js
function mostrarArchivo(input) {
  if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
    let reader = new FileReader();
    
    reader.onload = function(e) {
      let txt = document.getElementById("texto");
      txt.value = e.target.result;
    }
    
    reader.readAsText(input.files[0]); 
  }
}
```

```html
<form runat="server">
  <input type='file' id="archivo" /> <br />
  <textarea id="texto" style="width: 100%; max-width: 100%; height: 150px;">texto</textarea>
  <script>
  (function() {
    let arch = document.getElementById("archivo");
    arch.onchange = function() {
      mostrarArchivo(this);
    };
  })();
</script>  
</form>
```

Como ves, me estoy valiendo del evento `onchange()` del `input` para llamar a la rutina `mostrarArchivo` que, a su vez, lee el contenido del primer archivo seleccionado, como texto. Cuando la lectura termina, asigno el contenido leído al `textarea`.

Comment: Muchas gracias!!!! me sirvió a la perfección!

Comment: Un placer ser de ayuda.